# How to hide directories in Titanium Android?

Tags: android, titanium

I want my application images to not shown in Gallery.
Normally i use :

```
var dir = null;
if (OS_IOS || !Ti.Filesystem.isExternalStoragePresent()) {
    dir = Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory;
} else {
    dir = Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory;
}
var localStorage = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(dir, "AppImages");
if (!localStorage.exists()) {
    localStorage.createDirectory();
}
var imageFilePath = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(localStorage.resolve(), img.jpg);
```

To download and save images.But these pictures show in Gallery.How to use and write images that won't show in Android's Gallery ? I think when we write any file

```
imageFilePath.write(blob);
```

It is by default shown in Gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dir= Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory;
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(dir);
var list = f.getDirectoryListing();
if (list) {
for ( i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
Ti.Filesystem.getFile(dir + list[i]).isFile() && Ti.Filesystem.getFile(dir + list[i]).rename(“.”+newName);
   }
}
```

Run this code when your app goes in background.

Answer (score 2):

Just Create directory with name start with "." for e.g. - .MYDIR or .Gallery.

so Basicly in Internal sd or Whereever you want to save your Image, Create a Directory which Name Starts with "." (DOT) and save images into that Directory.

Hope it Helpes.

-Cheers

Aman

Comment: I have tried this @Aman but after device restart , the directories shows again with the original names.Another thing , if i have not used any directory , then how could i hide?

Comment: Did you try to save them with .bmp extension?